# reactjs: formik: onSubmit callback function: what parameters i can use

Tags: reactjs, formik

In Formik Form we see

```
<Formik
onSubmit={someCallBack}
>

</Formik>
```

And i have seen `someCallBack` function defined with various parameterts like

```
function someCallBack(values,props){
}

function someCallBack({setSubmitting}){
}
```

So how Formik know what parameters to be passed to the callback.

Can someone explain the syntax.

I can understand

```
onSubmit = {(e) => someCallBack(e,value,props)}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany ?

Comment: not able to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onSubmit: (values: Values, formikBag: FormikBag) => void | Promise<any>
```

> It is passed your forms values and the "FormikBag", which includes an object containing a subset of the injected props and methods (i.e. all the methods with names that start with set + resetForm) and any props that were passed to the wrapped component. Note: errors, touched, status and all event handlers are NOT included in the FormikBag.

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany